# jquerytools overlay initiated by onclick

Tags: jquery, onclick, overlay, jquery-tools

I'm trying to use [jQuerytools overlay](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/index.html) for confirmation dialogue. I have problem with the 'onclick' function to call the overlay.

**HTML**

```
<!-- list element -->
<ul>
    <li id="item1">
         <div class="listName">myListElement-1</div>
         <div class="listCtrlr"><span onclick="delItem(1, 'myListElement-1')" rel="#deldlg">delete</span></div>
    </li>
    <li id="item2">
         <div class="listName">myListElement-2</div>
         <div class="listCtrlr"><span onclick="delItem(2, 'myListElement-2')" rel="#deldlg">delete</span></div>
    </li>
    <li id="item3">
         <div class="listName">myListElement-3</div>
         <div class="listCtrlr"><span onclick="delItem(3, 'myListElement-3')" rel="#deldlg">delete</span></div>
    </li>
</ul>



<!-- overlay dialogue -->
<div id="deldlg" class="modd">
    <h5>Confirmation - Delete Campaign</h5>
    <div class="ctn">
        <p id="dq">Are you sure you want to permanently delete this data?</p>
        <p id="di"></p>
        <input type="button" value="Yes" id="delsubmit" class="brButton s grdRed">
        <input type="button" value="No" class="brButton s close">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function delItem(iid, iname) {
    var trigger = this;
    trigger.overlay({
                    fixed: false,
                    closeOnClick: false,
                    mask: {color:'#660000', loadSpeed:100, opacity:0.9},
                    onBeforeLoad:function() {
                                    jQuery('#di').html(iname);
                                    jQuery('#delsubmit').attr('onclick', 'del_camp('+iid+')');
                                }
                });
}
```

As I use the scripts above, it returns '***trigger.overlay is not a function***'. Could somebody help me to figure this out?

I'm expecting to have the following result (let's say I want to delete element-2)

```
Confirmation - Delete Campaign
-------------------------------------------------------------
Are you sure you want to permanently delete this data?

    myListElement-2

[ Yes ]     [ No ]
```

Comment: Have you ensure that `this` is actually what it is supposed to be? try using the developer tools in chrome or firebug to debug the JS and see what is happening in there.

Comment: @Nomad101 that's why I asked here, because I don't know which one is the right use of it - since it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be $(this).overlay(...) instead, as this is not a jquery object but a simple dom object thus not able  to access  jquery functions/plugins

Comment: since my scripts above didn't work, I thought about what you suggested there, and still there is no response at all with jQuery(this).overlay({...})

Comment: I saw better your code, I was sure we where inside a class.. THe right documentation for your case is this one http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html
inside a simple function you do not have this assigned to anything, that's why you get error; I would suggest something like $("#deldlg").overlay({}).....

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I now know what the issue you are having is. Ok so you need to either set an id explicitly for whatever HTML element you are using as the overlay. then use it like this `$("#findme").overlay({..});` The `this` object you were referring to was the scope of the function you were in, not a DOM element. At least from what I can tell of your code.

Comment: thanks for the response, @Nomad101. but, I still don't understand your '__The `this` object you were referring to was the scope of the function you were in, not a DOM element.__'